# Implementing blocking messages with Rabbitmq (or acking between publisher and consumer)

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, ack

I have 8 consumers on a queue and any of them can pick up messages and once processed, this effects the db. Most messages can be run async but on a few messages, we need to stop the queue consuming until that message has been fully processed by one of the consumers. During this time, the other 7 consumers shouldn't be consuming from the queue.

Is there anyway to implement this in rabbitmq rather than doing an application level solution (which might be very difficult to implement)?

Comment: When you get a synchronous message, do you need to stop processing all messages, or just process any synchronous messages serially?

Comment: @lreeder When a synchronous(blocking) message comes in, we need to stop getting all the messages after it (as they have to be processed with the assumption of the blocking message making changes to the db/cache) This is easy with one consumer, but not with 8 consumers, we  can't control the other 7 consumers without the help of rabbitmq

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a strictly RabbitMQ change to make that work.  However, here's an approach that doesn't require modification of any old code, aside from renaming the queue the producer is dropping messages on.  It does require writing a new consumer:

1. Create a queue with a single consume, and update your producer to send messages to that queue.
2. The consumer for that queue should  process any synchronous message.
3. Since it's a single consumer, all the other messages will block in the queue until it's done  processing.
4. The single consumer should forward any asynchronous messages to the original queue for the other eight consumers to process.

Since the single consumer is just forwarding the asynchronous messages, it  can do it quickly and there shouldn't be problem with throughput.